# RESET in Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, gpio

I'm using this Microcontroller [S32K142](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) 64 pin.

I want to understand to whether the RESET pin is Input or Output from the Microcontroller.

I checked the Microcontroller Reference Manual, it is given as I/O.

Can someone tell me whether it is Input or Output ?

[image]

Comment: What are the headings on the columns of the table, particularly the third column?

Comment: Also, please provide a link to the reference manual for the processor family.

Comment: Can't find this table in the datasheet you have attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says, it is an I/O, so it's both. Which is almost always the case with reset pins on every MCUs out there. They are almost always active low as well.

When the MCU is resetting, it will pull this pin low. You can also force a MCU reset from an external source by pulling it low. Common EMC practice is to provide an external pull-up there (~10k) to prevent accidental resets, though most modern MCUs have built-in pull-up.

Some MCUs may be picky about the value of a capacitor placed on the reset pin too - always check what value the manufacturer recommends to place there.

Comment: The "almost always" meaning, I have never ever found a MCU by any manufacturer behaving differently. But some exotic oddball part might exist, who knows...

Comment: Also, according to reference manual: RESET_B is a shared pin (See IO Signal Description Input Multiplexing sheet(s) attached to the Reference Manual). The user must configure the corresponding PORT_PCR  register prior to using this pin as RESET_B. On any reset event, the MCU configures the corresponding pad as RESET_B pad. Asserting RESET_B wakes the MCU from any mode. During a pin reset, the MCU writes 1 to RCM_SRS[PIN]. And in IO Signal Description Input Multiplexing sheet(s) attached to the Reference Manual it says it can be multiplexed as PTA5/TCLK1/RESET_b

Comment: The RESET pin on the ATmega 328 and its cousins is input-only by default. The RST pin on the MSP432 is input-only. The RST pin on the TM4C123 is input-only. The RESET input on the LPC13xx is input-only by default but can be configured as a GPIO pin. You need to get out more.

Comment: I think the "almost always" depends on what your past experience is, but I would not say that in an answer. It might be more common among currently popular ARM-based MCUs so that is true, but many earlier popular MCUs such as 8-bit AVRs and PICs sure did not have bidirectional resets.

Comment: Can you all give me one common answer, please? Whether the RESET is Input or Output pin in this S32K142 Microcontroller

Comment: @Newbie this answer is correct already. It is both an input and output, a bi-directional IO pin.

Comment: Ok sure, thank you. So, I will consider the RESET to be a bi-directional IO Pin

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Fair enough, I was kind of expecting someone to post counter examples :) Although I have worked extensively with the Motorola side of things (Freescale/NXP) which this question is about, and their parts always work like this since forever. I haven't used S32 but it's going to work the same as all their older parts.

Comment: @Lundin I'm 70. I started with microprocessors in about 1975 ish. Way back when Reset pins were almost always input only. Things change :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon MC6800 from 1974 apparently had the pin as I/O.

Comment: @Lundin For interest: I started with the NatSemi "SC/MP" - [datasheet here](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/national/_dataSheets/SCMP_dataSheet.pdf) whose Reset is input only (table 1) _ I had to look that up to check but memory said it was input only.  | Next ws the MC6802 [datasheet here](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/43502.pdf) again input only and I had to look it up to check my recollection.

Comment: COSMAC 1802 ?, Z80?, Z8?, ST6?, 6502?, ... ? :-)

Comment: @Lundin  Just had a look at the MC6800 datasheet as it seemeed strange at that era to have a bidirectional rests (unlike my MC6802 which didn't have). The datsheet [here](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=2158135&part-number=MC6800) indicates it is input only. My recollection is that this was typical for microprocessors of the day.